# Remove WindowSystemMenuHint from QDialog in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to remove system menu and context menu from `QDialog` title bar in Qt.
I have written code below but it does not work.

```
Qt::WindowFlags flags = windowFlags();
Qt::WindowFlags helpFlag = Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint;
flags = flags & (~helpFlag);

Qt::WindowFlags systemMenuFlag = Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint;
flags = flags & (~systemMenuFlag);
setWindowFlags(flags);
```

when I print `windowFlags` I am getting following output which still contents `WindowSystemMenuHint`.

```
Qutout :: QFlags(0x1|0x2|0x1000|0x2000|0x8000000).
```

How can I remove `0x2000` i.e. `WindowSystemMenuHint`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Qt Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum)

> The `CustomizeWindowHint` flag is used to enable customization of the window controls. This flag must be set to allow the `WindowTitleHint`, `WindowSystemMenuHint`, `WindowMinimizeButtonHint`, `WindowMaximizeButtonHint` and `WindowCloseButtonHint` flags to be changed.

So try this:

```
Qt::WindowFlags flags = windowFlags();
flags |= Qt::CustomizeWindowHint;
flags &= ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint;
flags &= ~Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint;
setWindowFlags(flags);
```

**Update for Qt 4.8**

Browsing through the [Qt source](https://github.com/qt/qt/blob/4.8/src/gui/kernel/qwidget.cpp#L1242), you can see that the system menu hint is restored when either of `Qt::WindowMinMaxButtonsHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint` is set.

So this will do it:

```
Qt::WindowFlags flags = windowFlags();
flags |= Qt::CustomizeWindowHint;
flags &= ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint;
flags &= ~Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint;
flags &= ~Qt::WindowMinMaxButtonsHint;
flags &= ~Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint;
setWindowFlags(flags);
```

But you will not have a close button anymore.

Comment: Not working. Output is :: QFlags(0x1|0x2|0x1000|0x2000|0x2000000|0x8000000)

Comment: Which Qt version are you using? It's working for me with Qt 5.7.0 . Output is: `QFlags<Qt::WindowType>(Dialog|WindowTitleHint|CustomizeWindowHint|WindowCloseButtonHint)`

Comment: I am using Qt 4.8.4